# use if-elseif -else with input from compare-object

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am comparing 2 *.csv* files and outputting the result to another *.csv* file. I can't seem to figure out how to further handle the compare-object result to be used in the `if..elseif...else{}` statement to print the result based on the `sideIndicator` result. Please further advise. Is there any catch I need to include to make sure the script will be handled properly?

```
clear-host
$northdb = Import-Csv "C:\temp\cep\Book1.csv" -Header "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" | Sort-object -Property "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" -unique 
$sdb = Import-Csv "C:\temp\cep\Book2.csv" -Header "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" | Sort-object -Property "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" -unique
$result = Compare-Object $northdb $sdb -Property  "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" -PassThru | 
if ($_SideIndicator -eq '=>') {Select-Object  "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv -NoTypeInfo} 
elseif ($_.sideIndicator -eq '=>') {Select-Object  "InstanceName", "DatabaseName", "PrinicipalName", "PrinicipalType", "Permission", "ObjectTypeLevel", "ObjectName" | export-csv C:\temp\cep\gogo.csv -NoTypeInfo} 
else {write-host "there is no changes"}
```

Comment: Your `if` and `elseif` conditions and blocks are completely identical, what would be the point?

Comment: There are all sorts of typos in that example. Misspelled principal, missing dot after the $_ in the first if, same condition in the if/elseif (should be <= in the else if), exporting both sides to same file, ... Clean up the code, and you may solve your problem.